# Is there a way to make a logbook in excel of files being created?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a dynamic excel sheet that updates whenever a file is being created into a folder, think of letters. So the sheet needs to extract the name of the letter, the date&time when it is made, the author and so on, into a table in excel. Does anyone knows how to get that filedata?

I already know how to put data in a certain cell using VBA but the thing i get stuck in is how to get that data from a certain folder.

Comment: There is no event in Excel that can monitor the folder.  You'd have to write some Windows code to create that.  The FileData can be obtained in various ways.  One method would be using the `FileSystemObject`

Comment: thanks for the response! Which program would you use for that? because if I understand you correctly, this can't be done with VBA right?

Comment: Perhaps, building on MJ's idea, a worksheet_activate event to update the list would be sufficient? I am not aware of any off the shelf program that will do what you want. Maybe there's something like File Explorer out there, but you'd have to research that.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. Getting the data is fairly straightforward depending on which data you want. You can use either the FileSystemObject or, for extended properties, Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation.  It is triggering the worksheet to update whenever the contents of the directory changes that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Ron said, there is no event in VBA to handle that. However, if you want to stick to VBA only, you have basically two options:

1. You can update your cell whenever the workbook is opened using the Workbook.Open event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open). This is not really dynamic but might be sufficient (depending on your needs).
2. Other option would be to call a function periodically to check if the folder content has changed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime)... Not very performant, but would work for sure.

For the file data just follow Ron's suggestion.

Hope that helps, MJ.